# Why are background images so zoomed in on iPhone?

Tags: android, html, iphone, zooming, blurry

I'm working on [my new website](http://annezwagers.com), and it's working perfectly on my phone. But unfortunately I noticed that it isn't working at all on iPhones. And only on iPhone.. (I already had a little aversion to Apple but now it's growing..)

The full screen background images are blurry and zoomed in like 1000%.. I don't understand why it working on all android devices and not on iphone 5/6. Couln't try older iPhones. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0kd1.jpg) a preview of the representation. I also tried a few CSS settings, but doesn't work out either.

First I thought it was a viewport issue, so I tried all kind of meta viewports, now using :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

But it still doesn't work. Is it because of the high resolution of the new iPhones? Then viewport should fix it, right?

I already have spent too much time trying to fix this, hope you can help me out!